# Vertex connectivity in circumscribed simple line arrangements

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-connectivity

An arrangement of $s$ lines are drawn in the plane so that no three lines intersect at a common point and no two lines are parallel. Now circumscribe this arrangement by a circle so that all intersections are in the interior of the circle. Denote the circumscribed line arrangement by $\mathcal{H}_{s}$. Is this arrangement $3$ $vertex-connected$ ?

Here was my attack. Let $x$ be any point on the boundary and suppose that $x$ is adjacent to the boundary points $a$ and $b$ and an interior point say $c$. Now $deg(x)=3$. Removal of $a$, $b$ and $c$ disconnects $x$ from $H_{s}$? In particular $(a,b,c)$ is a vertex cut?

I am not certain I understand vertex-connectivity correctly and I might be confusing it with edge-connectivity?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guess the vertex-connectivity of the above graph is 3.

The [vertex connectivity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VertexConnectivity.html) of graph $G$   denoted by $\kappa(G)$ is the minimum number of **vertex** whose removal yields to disconnected graph. In  analogical way, the [edge connectivity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EdgeConnectivity.html) of graph $G$  denoted by $\lambda (G)$  is the minimum number of **edges** whose removal yields to disconnected graph.They are related in the following inquality:
$$\kappa(G) \leq \lambda (G) \leq \delta(G)$$
where $\delta(G)$ is the minimum degree of $G$

**Example:**

-Any tree has vertex connectivity equal to 1.

-The complete graph on $n$ vertices has edge-connectivity equal to $n-1$.